# Printing a control Form

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Framework = .NET 4.5
Language = C#

I am working on a relatively simple program whose goal it is to replace an IBM Lotus Notes database application with a .NET Windows application.  I've run into a bit of a snag, however.

In Notes, it is very easy for me to select the documents I want to print out and then all selected documents from a view will be printed out using a selected form.  I would like to try to replicate this effect in my WPF application.  I have been reading up on the topic, and I can in fact print out a single document using a visual (in this case a grid holds all of the form and user inputted data), and it does not look too bad other than the fact that I'd prefer to have things look slightly different on the printout, i.e. DatePicker set to not show its selection button.

Here is my actual question.  Is it possible to create such a "Form" taking into account that the location of data must be strictly located at a certain point on the page (FlowDocument would therefore not be the best idea) while allowing me to use this single element as a master to print out multiple forms with one click of the print button (document selection not included)?  And where might I find a good source for learning this method?

Comment: I have completed my own answer for this question, but I must wait a few hours before I can post it.  Ill be sure to do it tonight yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the record, this has been waiting until SO gave me permission to answer my own question.  I cannot say I agree with that 'logic'.

Alright, I managed to more or less figure something out, at least for now.  I am still going to print with visuals because it allows me to use the same xaml code that I already have been using.  It is not perfect, but I will share what I am have.

First, I already have a collection of objects that I want to print out.  This is for testing purposes as this will be and should be a collection that the user defines.  I then  pass that collection to my print function as follows:

```
private void Print_Test()
        {
            PrintDialog dlg = new PrintDialog();
            if (dlg.ShowDialog() == false) return;
            int i = 1;

            Size pageSize = new Size(dlg.PrintableAreaWidth, dlg.PrintableAreaHeight); //I found this Size object very important.  Without it I only got an empty page
            ReportPrintForm rf;
            foreach (KeyValuePair<String, Report> kvp in ((App)Application.Current).Reports)
            {
                rf = new ReportPrintForm(kvp.Value);
                rf.Measure(pageSize);
                rf.Arrange(new Rect(0, 0, pageSize.Width, pageSize.Height));
                dlg.PrintVisual(rf, "Job_" + i);
                i++;
            }
        }
```

Now, I know that this is not a perfect function as each form is printed in its own job, but it is a starting point to solve my issue of using one strictly created "Form" to print out multiple objects.  This will print out that form without the user seeing it, which is good if I want to use one set of styles for the user presentation and one for the printable version.  A downside was that, at least for now, I had to set the content of the fields (TextBoxes) manually and could not rely on the DataContext field.  I do not know why, but again, this is only  starting point to finish my problem later.